# Twitter - Upload Image Using API and Get URL

Tags: twitter

I am creating a twitter share button that a user can click but I also want to attach an image to the tweet.

I am uploading the image to Twitter using the API so have the media ID available.

Is there a way to get the URL from this ID so I can attatch it to a Twitter Intent link?

Or can I only use this Media ID with the API to post a tweet for an authenticated user?

I am trying to attatch a Twitter hosted Image to a Share button so that anybody can post it to their Twitter feed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can attach the image to a tweet, you would need to upload the image to twitter first. I think you are already doing this using the endpoint media/upload

Reference:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload

Once this is done issue another POST request to the endpoint statuses/update with parameters 'status' and 'media_ids'. Twitter expects a comma separated list of media_ids. You already have this in the object returned by media/upload endpoint.

Reference:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update

The object returned in the above call has the url for each media uploaded under the property entities.

This is an excerpt from how I did using PHP and abrahamoauth library. $connection is the twitter connection object.

```
$media = $connection->upload('media/upload', array('media' => $_FILES["tweet_image_file"]["tmp_name"]));
$parameters = array(
                'status' => '',
                'media_ids' => implode(',', array($media->media_id_string)),
            );

$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
//$image_url = $result->entities->media[0]->media_url; //stopped working from July 2015
$image_url = $result->entities->media[0]->url;
```